# react-router two way binding of query parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

suppose I have a route path `#/plugin?search=:q`, and that query parameter `q` will be put into my search input box, that's okay. The question is if I change the content of my search input box, how can I make the change reflect in the URL path. Say if I type in `react` in the search inbox, then I want the URL path become `#/plugin?search=react`. Is this doable with react router?

Answer (score 0):

That would mean you need to create your routes manually, using `Route.create` method. then create a router instance to hold your routes on each render of your component. hope this idea helps.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you come up with some sample code?

Comment: ````var router = Router.create({

  routes: 'your newly created path'

  location: Router.HistoryLocation

});```


```React.createClass({
  handleUserInput(event) {
    this.setState({route: event.target.value});
  },
  render() {
    return <RouteHandler/>
  }
});```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.params` could help you.`:q` is a variable stored inside `this.props.params` of your component, you could access it and assigning it a value of your research (see [react-router routeParams](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#routeparams) !).